# Python singleton / object instantiation

Tags: python, singleton

I'm learning Python and i've been trying to implement a Singleton-type class as a test. The code i have is as follows:

```
_Singleton__instance = None

class Singleton:
    def __init__(self):
        global __instance
        if __instance == None:           
            self.name = "The one"
            __instance = self
        else:
            self = __instance
```

This works in part but the self = __instance part seems to be failing. I've included some output from the interpretor to demonstrate (the code above is saved in singleton.py):

```
>>> import singleton
>>> x = singleton.Singleton()
>>> x.name
'The one'
>>> singleton._Singleton__instance.name
'The one'
>>> y = singleton.Singleton()
>>> y.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Singleton instance has no attribute 'name'
>>> type(y)
<type 'instance'>
>>> dir(y)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
```

Is it possible to do what i'm trying? If not is there another way of doing this?

Any suggestions welcome.

Cheers.

Comment: Other than an interesting learning exercise, do you have a use case for this Singleton?  Sometimes Singletons can be much more simply than this.  The Singleton design pattern -- to an extent -- is a Smalltalk/C++/Java-ism that isn't often needed in Python.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assigning to an argument or any other local variable (barename) cannot ever, possibly have ANY effect outside the function; that applies to your `self = whatever` as it would to ANY other assignment to a (barename) argument or other local variable.

Rather, override `__new__`:

```
class Singleton(object):

    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance == None:
            cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
            cls.__instance.name = "The one"
        return cls.__instance
```

I've done other enhancements here, such as uprooting the global, the old-style class, etc.

MUCH better is to use [Borg](http://www.aleax.it/5ep.html) (aka monostate) instead of your chosen Highlander (aka singleton), but that's a different issue from the one you're asking about;-).

Comment: Eheh, SO is sponsoring his (great) creature here :) I agree, of course

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess i haven't got my head around the __init__ method as much as i thought i had; i was fooled by the self.name effecting the object but i guess this is a bit of Python magic?. 

The question was more about understanding Python than using the Singleton pattern but i'll check out the Borg link anyway :)

Comment: self.name is a QUALIFIED name, not a BARENAME: assigning to a barename and assigning to a qualified name are potentially ENTIRELY different operations -- I devote QUITE a bit of space to that in the appropriate chapters of "Python in a Nutshell", too much to repeat everything here, so I suggest you read that (maybe from one of the many pirate copies on the net: as the author I'm NOT happy about them, but there sure ARE a huge number!-)

Comment: With 2.6 on Debian squeeze, I get "TypeError: type.__new__(Singleton): Singleton is not a subtype of type" when  trying to instantiate this class.

Comment: Faheem the OP named his class "Singleton"

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't each ``__instance`` be ``cls.__instance`` and ``type`` should be ``object`` ??

Answer (score 6):

[Bruce Eckel's code snippet from Design Pattern: I'm confused on how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296311/bruce-eckels-code-snippet-from-design-pattern-im-confused-on-how-it-works)

```
class Borg:
  _shared_state = {}
  def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = self._shared_state

class MySingleton(Borg):
  def __init__(self, arg):
    Borg.__init__(self)
    self.val = arg
  def __str__(self): return self.val

x = MySingleton('sausage')
print x
y = MySingleton('eggs')
print y
z = MySingleton('spam')
print z
print x
print y
print ´x´
print ´y´
print ´z´
output = '''
sausage
eggs
spam
spam
spam
<__main__. MySingleton instance at 0079EF2C>
<__main__. MySingleton instance at 0079E10C>
<__main__. MySingleton instance at 00798F9C>
'''
```

Comment: +1 for this reference.  In particular, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296311/bruce-eckels-code-snippet-from-design-pattern-im-confused-on-how-it-works/1297577#1297577

Answer (score 4):

**From [Singleton Pattern (Python)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Python)**:

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, dict):
        super(Singleton, self).__init__(name, bases, dict)
        self.instance = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kw)

        return self.instance

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

print MyClass()
print MyClass()
```

Comment: why does you Singleton inherit "type"? What is type? Why not object?

Comment: This way of implementing Singleton calls __init__ twice, which caused me a lot of headache, overriding modified variables back to the original initializations.

Answer (score 3):

This is about the most basic Singleton you can make.  It uses a [class method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) to check whether the singleton has been created and makes a new one if it hasn't.  There are more advanced ways of going about this, such as overriding the [`__new__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

```
class Singleton:
    instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = cls()
        return cls.instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5       # or whatever you want to do

sing = Singleton.get()
print sing.x  # prints 5
```

As for why your code fails, there are several reasons.  First, by the time `__init__` is called, a new object has already been created, defeating the purpose of the singleton pattern.  Second, when you say `self = __instance`, that simply resets the local variable self; this would be akin to saying

```
def f(x):
  x = 7    # changes the value of our local variable

y = 5
f(y)
print y   # this is still 5
```

Since variables in Python are passed by value and not reference, you can't say `self = blah` and have it be meaningful in the way you want.  The above Singleton class is more what you want, unless you want to get fancy and look into overriding the `__new__` operator.

Comment: they are passed by sharing and not by reference, value: http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm.

Answer (score 0):

```
self = _instance
```

This wont do what you are expecting it to do. Read about how Python treats names.