# How to adapt the Singleton pattern? (Deprecation warning)

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton, deprecated

Few years ago I found an implementation of the Singleton pattern in Python by [Duncan Booth](http://web.archive.org/web/20090619190842/http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html):

```
class Singleton(object):
    """
    Singleton class by Duncan Booth.
    Multiple object variables refers to the same object.
    http://web.archive.org/web/20090619190842/http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html#singleton-and-the-borg
    """
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                               cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

The same approach is also described in question "[Is there a simple, elegant way to define Singletons in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python/1810391#1810391)"

I use the Singleton via sub-classing:
`class Settings(Singleton)`
`class Debug(Singleton)`

Recently I made some changes to the program and got this warning:

```
/media/KINGSTON/Sumid/src/miscutil.py:39: DeprecationWarning: 
object.__new__() takes no parameters
cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

I found [explanation](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/076854.html) (by Guido) about `__new__` deprecation which says that the parameters are not used at all. Passing an argument which is not needed can be symptom of a bug.

So I decided to clear the parameters:

```
class Singleton(object):
_instance = None

def __new__(cls):
    if not cls._instance:
        cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__()
    return cls._instance
```

Which resulted in following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "sumid.py", line 1168, in <module>
  settings = Settings()
 File "/media/KINGSTON/Sumid/src/miscutil.py", line 45, in __new__
  cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__()
 TypeError: object.__new__(): not enough arguments
```

When I modify the line to `cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)`, I'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sumid.py", line 1174, in <module>
    debug = Debug(settings)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Gimmel suggest another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590477/python-deprecation-warnings-with-monostate-new-can-someone-explain-why/1590586#1590586): `_instance = type.__new__(cls)`. For me it breaks the inheritance:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sumid.py", line 1168, in <module>
    settings = Settings()
  File "/media/KINGSTON/Sumid/src/miscutil.py", line 40, in __new__
    _instance = type.__new__(cls)
TypeError: type.__new__(Settings): Settings is not a subtype of type
```

The same [problem](http://freshfoo.com/blog/object__init__takes_no_parameters) has also Menno Smits. But I don't understand the [solution](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127) suggested. Moreover I have no multiple inheritance in relevant code.

I didn't try the another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python/33201#33201) in "Is there a simple, elegant way to define Singletons in Python?", but at a glance it probably will have the same problem.

I use the Singleton pattern in a program and I don't want to rewrite it completely just because one warning. Thus following answers wont help me:

- Singleton is wrong. Don't use the Singleton at all.
- Use Borg instead, it's more pythonic.
- Use module instead of a class.

To conclude I'll repeat the question:
How to **adapt the Singleton** pattern with consideration of the **deprecation warning** with the **minimal impact** to existing code?

**Edit:**
Line `cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)` raises the TypeError when the Child's init takes an argument:

```
class Child(Singleton):
    def __init__(self,param=None):
        print(param)
        print("Doing another stuff.")

ch = Child("Some stuff")
```

Comment: You have probably already looked at Alex Martelli's http://www.aleax.it/gdd_pydp.pdf (slides 20-..), but anyway. (I just remember him talking about the Singleton's cons in that talk (one can watch it at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJJlVBVTFg))

Comment: @mlvljr interesting. Thanks. But the Singleton pattern on P20 has the same problem - deprecation warning. They solve it with Borg - which will raise the same warning.

Comment: A few links discussing this issue: 1. [The bug report that caused the issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1683368) 2. [A discussion of a similar problem](http://freshfoo.com/blog/object__init__takes_no_parameters).

Comment: @Sven Thanks. Could you please be more specific with the text linked as first? I don't see there a clue for the inheritance with overridden `init` or `new`. Just at the end is outlined the issue and the link to Menno's Musings.    

Yes, I'm aware of the second link. I state in the original question that I don't understand the solution proposed by Benjamin in discussion below.

Comment: @sumid: Sorry, I missed that you linked the second one in your post.  Might be the only link of your post I didn't click.  The first link is the bug report that discusses if `object.__new__()` and `object.__init__()` should accept additional parameters (and ignore them) and if yes, in what circumstances.  It also contains a serious of patches to the Python source that show the exact logic when `object.__new__()` accepts arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to drop any additional arguments you are passing when you construct the object. Change the offending line to:

```
        cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
```

or

```
        cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
```

though I think you'll be fine with the first (diamond inheritance and singletons sound as though they shouldn't be mixed).

P.S. I did try this suggestion and it works for me so I don't know why it didn't work for you.

**Edit in response to @dragonx's comment:** As pointed out in the comments, `object.__new__` will throw an exception if you pass on `*args, **kwargs` so the super call to `__new__` should not include any arguments apart from `cls`. This wasn't the case when the original article was written. Also of course if you choose to base your singleton on some other type such as a `tuple` you would then need to pass the appropriate arguments.

Comment: It raises the Error when the Child's init takes some argument:

`     class Child(Singleton):  
         def __init__(self,param=None):  
                 print param  
                 print 'Doing another stuff'  
    
    ch=Child('Some stuff')`  


I did think that __new__() goes first and __init__ goes after that. I don't understand why they should have same parameters. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

So based on the answers from @Sven and @Duncan I found a solution which works for me. The problem actually wasn't in the line of the code raising the TypeError, but in the signature of the `__new__()` method. The call of the `object.__new__(cls)` shall be without the *args, **kwargs, but they have to remain in the `Singleton.__new__()` definition. This is the modified Singleton:

```
class Singleton(object):
    """
    Singleton class by Duncan Booth.
    Multiple object variables refers to the same object.
    http://www.suttoncourtenay.org.uk/duncan/accu/pythonpatterns.html
    """
   _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance
```

And this is an example of sub-classing (which was the issue):

```
class Child(Singleton):  
    def __init__(self,param=None):  
            print param  
            print 'Doing another stuff'  

ch=Child('Some stuff')
```

I still don't understand why the signature of Child's `__init__()` has to match to Singleton's `**new**(), but this solution **works**.

Comment: If `A` is a class, then `A(1, 2, 3)` first calls `A.__new__(A, 1, 2, 3)`.  If the object `obj` returned by this call is of type `A` again, `obj.__init__(1, 2, 3)` will be called.  Note that even for the singleton `__init__()` is called each time you request the instance.  The described behaviour is the behaviour of the standard metaclass `type`.  If you don't like it, you can derive your own metaclass from `type` and overwrite `type.__call__()`.

Comment: FWIW, the way things stand nowadays, Duncan's original version with `__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` works in Python 2.7.5, but results in a `TypeError: object() takes no parameters` in Python 3.3.2. However `__new__(cls)` works correctly in both.

Answer (score 0):

I found this pattern described in a Python 3 pattern and idioms source. This should certainly help. I would love to know if it solves your problem, although it may violate the minimal impact condition in your question.

[Python 3: The Singleton](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Singleton.html)